# Why don't Sri Vaishnava acharyas recommend veganism?

Tags: sri-vaishnava, food, gunas, cows, diet

According to Sanatana Dharma, store bought milk is considered highly sinful. This is what the Dharma shastra says:

> The milk of the cow that has not passed its ten days... as also the milk of the cow without her calf. - Manusmriti [verse 5.8](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc200382.html)

What this is referring to is this: When a cow gives birth to a calf, for the first 10 days after giving birth, the cow cannot be milked; all of its milk goes to its calf.

Also, a cow should only be milked by showing it its own calf. It cannot be milked by showing it another calf, and it cannot be milked by itself.

What this means is that the modern milk industry's practice of milking cows as soon as they give birth, and by using a machine, is highly sinful.

This prohibition of store bought milk is also mentioned in Vedanta Desikan's [Ahara Niyamam](http://www.srivaishnavam.com/desikaprabandam/ahara_meaning.htm). This text contains foods that are sattvic, and those that are not sattvic. Impure milk like store-bought milk is not considered sattvic and is considered tamasic.

And Vedanta Desikan in his [*Rahasya Traya Sara*](https://archive.org/details/rahasyatrayasaraofsrivedantadesikaengmrrajagopalaayyangar1946ocr/page/n362/mode/1up?view=theater) cites a scriptural verse (which is not mentioned by the editor) describing a very severe consequence for people who drink such kind of impure milk:

> "He who eats white egg plant....cheese (or curds) made from the milk of a cow within ten days of its calving - **he will never think in his last moments of Bhagavan, the Lord of the world.**

And thinking of Bhagavan in the last moments before death is involved in Bhakti yoga that is mentioned in the Bhagavad Gita.

However, Sri Vaishnavas continue to consume this kind of dairy. Given the very clear prohibition, why do so many Sri Vaishnava swamis, jeeyars, acharyas, mathams, and devotees consume store bought dairy? In Sri Vaishnava lectures, the lecturers never tell people to stop drinking milk and go vegan; they only tell people to give up alcohol, onion, garlic, etc.

Vegans abstain from all dairy products because the dairy industry is inhumane. So why don't Sri Vaishnava acharyas do it too?

Is it because it is too inconvenient for south Indian Brahmins to give up curd rice and milk? I believe that this is the only satisfactory answer.

Unless they own a goshala and milk the cows themselves, or get the milk from a Vedic goshala, Sri Vaishnavas will have to consume impure milk. And giving up dairy is not an option because it is *too impractical* since curd, milk, and ghee are a *core part* of south Indian Brahmin cuisine, unlike onion, garlic, etc. which are not essentials in the cuisine.

Comment: the Q is self-answering "And giving up dairy is not an option because it is too impractical since curd, milk, and ghee are a core part of south Indian Brahmin cuisine," @ikshvaku

Comment: @SK That's my educated guess, but I want to hear the sampradaya's official answer on this, if they even have an answer.

Comment: the concept of veganism arose only in 1944.  It wasn't possible for ancient and medieval Hindus to recommend it. @ikshvaku

Comment: In fact milk etc is part of food that one can have during fasts. Probably they don’t recommend because they’re not aware of the horrors of the dairy industry?? Even the horrors of the industry are modern. In the ancient days people treated cows properly.

Comment: Take for example Bhagavan himself. He would take his cows to graze and play his flute to call them back. As opposed, Modern days, cows maybe locked up in one place or if they’re taken out, they are forcibly brought back. In India at least they followed the old system of flute etc. modern dairy practices are modern and acharyas may simply not be aware of them. Or May simply have no option but to make do?

Comment: better to take milk from local goshala. or reduce consumption of store brought milk. cheese/pizza etc. can be avoided more easily. many ashrams do have a local goshala either within, or next to their premises.

Comment: @mar What if there are no local goshalas? Also, they charge A LOT. It's expensive to keep one running and that's why many goshalas in India are selling their cows. So basically we have to go vegan. Why don't any acharyas recommend veganism?

Comment: @mar For example, srirangam narayana matham in srirangam, TN sold their goshala because it was too expensive. Narasimha temple in Mysore sold their goshala for the same reason, etc. Acharyas only recommend giving up the usual "onion, garlic, liquor, etc", but never dairy like Westerners do. Why not? The clear answer is because dairy products, like curd rice, ghee, milk, etc, is fundamental to south Indian brahmin diet, unlike western diet.

Comment: @Ikshvaku - because the goal is to do both - be vegetarian AND humane. ghee is necessary to do havis (yagna). you might argue that being humane trumps being vegetarian. however, we do not know deva rahasya. if harming cows to do yagna does more good to world, then so be it. if not, then go vegan. any case, where there is a will, there is a way, and reward is proportional to effort/tapasya.

Comment: @mar That makes sense, thanks